# GULP - smooth conversion of js files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

Question:

How to do that by editing the script.js file in the src directory, the script.js file in the public directory was working. Until now, the gulp has been suspended while editing this first file.

The problem arises when I want to use gulp-uglify and gulp-babel (compilation to the older version + mimification) or gulp-uglifyes (does the same). Without them everything is laughing :)

CODE
https://github.com/dominikjankowski/gulp

Comment: I see gulp-uglifyes in your gulpfile.  My search doesn't show such a thing.  Where did you get that?

Comment: You are right, I had changed gulpfile.js before I pushed it to the repository. https://github.com/dominikjankowski/gulp <-->this is that version, which does not work correctly.